# Is usage of memo() allowed inside functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I need to create an animated component inside of another function component (there are reasons as to why I can't to do this outside of it).

So far most optimal and cleanest solution I cam up with is following

```
export function Input({ placeholder }) {
  const AnimatedText = memo(Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Ui.Text))

  return (
    <AnimatedText>
      {placeholder}
    </AnimatedText>
  )
}
```

I think this works, but have never used memo like this inside a functional component and after looking in the docs, was not able to determine if this is allowed or not, hence this question: Is this ok to do, or should I use `useMemo` with empty dep array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any valid React component, including functions and forwardRef components, is accepted.

Reference: https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#parameters

You can do so, but react recommends not creating component in a component.

---

You may not need to use memo

https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#should-you-add-memo-everywhere